# How to find max and return adjacent cell in Excel

Tags: excel, max

Imagine a table:

```
Red 8 Black 1    
Red 2 Black 3    
Red 1 Black 0    
Red 7 Black 8    
Red 4 Black 5
```

How do I return "Red" or "Black" in a third column for each row depending on which has a larger value?

It would be:

```
Red 8 Black 1 Red    
Red 2 Black 3 Black    
Red 1 Black 0 Red    
Red 7 Black 8 Black    
Red 4 Black 5 Black
```

Comment: I've only been able to find answers on how to find the largest of all the numbers. I need to do it on a per-row basis

Comment: What happens when the values are tied?

Comment: They never are in my set

Comment: is this for vba or an excel function?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=INDEX(A2:D2,MATCH(MAX(A2:D2),A2:D2,0)-1)
```

[image]

---

Edit:

Since there are only two Options, a simple IF will work:

```
=IF(B2>D2,A2,C2)
```

[image]

Comment: Remember to come back after the question is 15 minutes old to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.